# How does MySQL take variables in bash?

Tags: mysql, bash, authentication

Making a script to print out data from a MySQL db via bash, I met the following problem:
While I try to log in, it uses the password as the database to log in to.

Script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
db=$1
pasx=$2
CMD="use $db; select * from job_log;"
mysql -u sqluser -p "${pasx}" -e "$CMD"
```

If I'm going to run the script with the command

```
User@server:/path/with/file$ sh sql.sh ok hobo
```

MySQL returns the following:

> User@server:/path/with/file$ sh sql.sh ok hobo
>
> ok
>
> Enter password: ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'hobo'

I might have fully misunderstood something, but I can't put my finger on what it might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the space after the `-p` parameter. See the [mysql man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysql) page. You also need to specify the database in the command (remove it from the query)

```
mysql -u sqluser -p$pasx -e "$CMD" $db
```

Or maybe more clear:

```
mysql --user=sqluser --password=$pasx --execute="$CMD" $db
```

Comment: With the space in excess, the command was: `mysql -u sqluser -p hobo -e "use..."`. `hobo` was interpreted as the first parameter to `mysql`, ie. the database to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mysql -u sqluser --password=${pasx} -e "$CMD" $db
```